# How to pass string value to my web service written in C# from php?

Tags: php, .net, soap, nusoap

I want to call a soap web service written asp.net(C#).Actually,the web method takes one string as a parameter and return some string as output.

In client side(PHP) am using **nusoap** for accessing web service.

This is php code to calling my web service...

```
<?php

require_once('nusoap/lib/nusoap.php');
$wsdl="http://localhost/suppliers.asmx?WSDL";
$param=array('name'=>'saran');

$client = new soapclient($wsdl,'wsdl');
echo $client->call('ShowSuppliers',$param);
?>
```

But when i run this code, the echo statement simply displaying **Array** in the browser...

I don't know what is the problem here...

But when i tried to follow the Broncha approach something like this, it's working good...

Instead of directly using the echo statement, i tried like this

```
$result=$client->call('ShowSuppliers',$param);

foreach($result as $key => $value)
{
  echo $value;
}
```

What is the difference between these two's...

Please guide me to get out of this problem...

Comment: check your output with `var_dump($client->call('ShowSuppliers',$param);)`

Comment: @Broncha :i checked, the variable value also is Array...

Comment: @Broncha : but when i put code like this...It's working fine...                      foreach($result as $key => $value)
{
  echo $value;
}
What is the problem in my previous coding...

Comment: when you do `echo` you are trying to echo an array, which will just print `Array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$client->call('ShowSuppliers',$param); returns you an Array element so whenever you echo 
an array element it is seen as Array written in the browser. To print an Array either you can
use print_r(array name) or var_dump(array name);.

In the next code you are using foreach loop so it is parsing the array element into key and value pair..

Please dont used call('ShowSuppliers',$param); because call function has been deprecated please see the link http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.call.php

Instead use soapCall function please see the link http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php

It might create problem later onwards since the function is deprecated.